# PHP array_splice within loop not working as desired

Tags: php, function, array-splice

I'm using the following code and everything seems fine in this little bit.

```
$colors = array('red', 'yellow', 'blue');
$replacements = array('yellow' => array(1, 1), 'blue' => array('black','orange'));
foreach ($replacements as $color => $replace) {
    $position = array_search($color, $colors);
    array_splice($colors, $position, 1, $replace);
}
```

result of $colors:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => black
    [4] => orange
)
```

Now here's where I'm having the issue. If I simply change the $replacements array to the following (note the yellow array values changed):

```
$replacements = array('yellow' => array(0, 1), 'blue' => array('black','orange'));
```

and then run the code again I get the following undesired results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => black
    [2] => orange
    [3] => 1
    [4] => blue
)
```

The result above is not what I am expecting. The array_splice function seems to be having some sort of issue when a value of zero (0) is passed.

The desired result would be the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => black
    [4] => orange
)
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running afoul of `array_search()`'s default behavior of loose type comparisons. In PHP, [any string is considered equal to integer zero](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) when doing a loose comparison (`==`) rather than strict (`===`).

So on the second replacement, PHP sees `'blue'` as loosely equal to `0` from the first replacement, and substitutes `'black','orange'` where the `0` had been.

```
var_dump('blue' == 0);
// bool(true)
var_dump('blue' === 0);
// bool(false)
```

To make [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) compare strictly, pass `TRUE` as its third parameter. You'll then get the expected result.

```
$colors = array('red', 'yellow', 'blue');
$replacements = array('yellow' => array(0, 1), 'blue' => array('black','orange'));
foreach ($replacements as $color => $replace) {
    // Use a strict comparison with TRUE as the 3rd arg
    $position = array_search($color, $colors, TRUE);
    array_splice($colors, $position, 1, $replace);
}

print_r($colors);
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => black
    [4] => orange
)
```